# Access target Python callable from Celery task instance

Tags: python, django, celery

Is there a way to access the callable Python object from a Celery task, either directly or through a lookup method (like Django's `get_model()). I've got a dot-notation reference to where the callable is declared but I need the actual object to get access to it's attributes before sending / calling the task.

I've scoured through the public and private methods but none of them seem obviously what I'm looking for:

```
$ dir(celery_task_instance)

> ['AsyncResult', 'MaxRetriesExceededError', 'OperationalError', 'Strategy',
'__bound__', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__',
'__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__',
'__hash__', '__header__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__',
'__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__',
'__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__',
'__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__trace__', '__v2_compat__', '__weakref__',
'__wrapped__', '_app', '_backend', '_decorated', '_default_request',
'_exec_options', '_get_app', '_get_exec_options', '_get_request',
'abstract', 'acks_late', 'add_around', 'add_to_chord', 'add_trail',
'after_return', 'annotate', 'app', 'apply', 'apply_async', 'autoregister',
'backend', 'bind', 'chunks', 'default_retry_delay', 'delay', 'expires',
'from_config', 'ignore_result', 'map', 'max_retries', 'name', 'on_bound',
'on_failure', 'on_retry', 'on_success', 'pop_request', 'push_request',
'rate_limit', 'reject_on_worker_lost', 'replace', 'request',
'request_stack', 'resultrepr_maxsize', 'retry', 'run', 's', 'send_event',
'send_events', 'serializer', 'shadow_name', 'si', 'signature', 'signature_from_request',
'soft_time_limit', 'starmap', 'start_strategy', 'store_errors_even_if_ignored', 'subtask',
'subtask_from_request', 'throws', 'time_limit', 'track_started', 'trail', 'update_state']
```

### Background

I'm using `django-celery-beat` to create scheduled tasks for Celery within a Django project.

I'd like to validate the schema of the `args` and `kwargs` fields at the time of creating the scheduled task, to anticipate and prevent future runtime issues. For example, API paramaters defined supplied via the `kwargs` field.

I can access the list of registered tasks in my Django `forms.ModelForm.clean()` method I've been able to access the registered Celery tasks. I thought that I could store the validation schema as an attribute of the the target `@shared_task` and then access that during task creation. The schema is defined as a `marshmallow.Schema` in case it's relevant but this could equally be hardcoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong place - `importlib` makes this fairly trivial. I was thinking it was something that I needed to get from Celery.

```
import importlib
split_path = dot_notation_path.split(".")
module_name, callable_name = ".".join(split_path[:-1]), split_path[-1]
module_object = importlib.import_module(module_name)
callable_object = getattr(somemodule, callable_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Having

```
@app.task(name='some_task')
def some_function_with_task_decorator(params: dict):
    do_sth()
```

`some_function_with_task_decorator` is of type `PromiseProxy`. To get the callable name use `some_function_with_task_decorator._get_current_object().__name__`

`some_function_with_task_decorator._get_current_object()`
gets the `Task` out of `PromiseProxy`

Since `Task` is a decorator use `__name__` to get the decorated function.
Then you could dynamically call the function as suggested in [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)